# How can I designate 'url' of 'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME' correctly?

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, webpack-loader, django-webpack-loader

I'm using `Django` and `react` with `webpack`

While setting up `WEBPACK_LOADER` in `settings.py`, I've faced the problem!
My file tree is like this.

***My File Tree***

```
Cebula4
    -  back
         - manage.py
    -  front
         - bundles
              - MainPage.js (webpacked)
```

and

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT' : {
            'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': '/front/bundles/',
            'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'front/webpack-stats.json'),

    }
}
```

I'd like to get a bundled(webpacked) file, `MainPage.js` but, `Server` said there is none at `that url`.[image]

Please understand my low level of programming,
  Could I ask what is the correct url that I can get exact `MainPage.js`?

**Added part of my `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT`**

```
STATIC_URL = '/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'staticfiles')
```

Comment: Have you tried `'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'bundles/',`?

Comment: @nik_m Thank you for answer, I did but there is no change :-(

Comment: Would you mind to show your `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` settings?

Comment: @nik_m I added what you want, thanks!